# R- table of a feature in dataframe, but only if x occurances

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R, and when I do something such as:

```
table(data$brand)
```

I get about a hundred factors (many with 0 after cleaning data), and many with only 1 or 2 occurances. I only care about ones that there are >50 occurrences of.  Is there a way to get a table like this instead of reading through the long list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset

```
tbl <- table(data$brand)
tbl[tbl > 50]
```